# Referencing a csv within a zip file by its absolute path

Tags: python, csv, zip

I have a bunch of zip files within a directory, and each zip file contains a few CSV's.  I'm curious if it's possible to get the files within each zip file, and then add their absolute paths to a list so they can be referenced directly later?

What I have so far is below:

```
# d is the directory with folders containing zip files
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(d):
    csv_list = []

    # Works since zip files are files and not folders
    for f in filenames:
        fp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))

        if zipfile.is_zipfile(fp): 
            # need to unzip and add contents
            names_to_add = zipfile.ZipFile(fp).namelist()
            paths_to_add = [os.path.join(fp, i) for i in names_to_add]

            # how do I get absolute paths to the CSV's?
            csv_list.extend(paths_to_add)

        else: 
            # will be a csv file already
            csv_list.append(fp)

# I want this to contain all absolute paths directly to CSV's
print csv_list
```

In other words, I want to treat the zip files like folders so I can ignore them and reference the CSV's within them directly.  Is this possible?  Or do I need to extract everything first?  If so, what would be an easy script I could run to extract all the files into folders with the same name?  Thanks.

**EDIT**: When trying to open any of the CSV files in the `csv_list`, I am getting the error:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\file\\path\\to\\csv\\in\\zip'`

Presumably this is because you can't reference a CSV within a zip file by its absolute path.  Could it be due to another reason?

Comment: I don't see why what you have will not work.  Can you give a specific example of what you are getting and what you want to get?

Comment: @tnknepp - Just updated with the error I'm receiving.  It relates directly to my question though, which is whether it's possible to reference a file within a zip file by its absolute path.